# Función Actualizar, enviar datos entre un componente hijo al padre y del padre al hijo Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy tratando de enviar información cuando hago click en el boton editar, necesito cargar los datos al los respectivos input, estoy usando @Output para enviar los datos al app.component y un @Input para enviarla al FormComponent.. cuando tengo la información en el componente no sé en que momento ni como setear los valores de los input estoy usando ngForms drive Templates.. Alguien podria ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi app.component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Card } from './interfaces/Card.inteface';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { TarjetaService } from './services/tarjeta.service';
import { tap } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  listCards: Card[] = [];
  
  dataUpdate:Card = {
    id: 0,
    titular:'',
    numeroTarjeta:'',
    fechaExpriracion:'',
    cvvPassword:''
  };

  constructor(private toastr: ToastrService, private getTarjetaSvc: TarjetaService){}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getTarjetas();
  }

  getTarjetas(): void {
    this.getTarjetaSvc.getListTarjetas().pipe(
      tap(cards => this.listCards = cards),
      tap(cards => console.log(cards)))
    .subscribe()
  }

  addCard(card: Card): void {
    this.getTarjetaSvc.saveTarjeta(card).pipe(
      tap(res => {
        this.toastr.success('La tarjeta se ha añadido exitosamente', 'Operacion Exitosa!')
        this.getTarjetas();
      })
    ).subscribe()
  }

  deleteCard(index: number): void{
    this.getTarjetaSvc.deleteTarjeta(index).pipe(
      tap(res =>{
        this.toastr.error('La tarjeta se ha eliminada exitosamente', 'Operacion Exitosa!')
        this.getTarjetas()
      })
    ).subscribe();

  }

  updateCard(updateData:Card){
    this.dataUpdate = updateData
  }
}

Este es el .ts del component, aqui guardo y envio los datos, en este punto ya tengo los datos de la card que deseo editar:
```

```html
<div class=" flex justify-between font-bold text-white text-2xl bg-green-700 p-4 shadow-sm shadow-green-400">
    <h1>Tajertas de Credito App</h1>
    <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
</div>
<div class="container mx-auto">
    <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-evenly space-x-3">
        <app-tatjeta-credito-form
            (Card)="addCard($event)"
            [dataUpdate] ="dataUpdate" 
        ></app-tatjeta-credito-form>
        <app-tarjeta-credito-view 
            [listCards]="listCards"
            (indexCardForDelete)="deleteCard($event)"
            (updateData)="updateCard($event)"
        ></app-tarjeta-credito-view>

        {{dataUpdate | json}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Este es el componente del form donde deseo rellenar los input y estoy resiviendo los datos con un @Input:

```js
import { ValueConverter } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/view/template';
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Card } from 'src/app/interfaces/Card.inteface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tatjeta-credito-form',
  templateUrl: './tatjeta-credito-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tatjeta-credito-form.component.css']
})
export class TatjetaCreditoFormComponent{
  
  model = {
    id:0,
    titular:'',
    numeroTarjeta:'',
    fechaExpriracion:'',
    cvvPassword:''
  }

  @Input() dataUpdate!:Card
  @Output() Card = new EventEmitter<Card>()
    
  onSubmit(form:NgForm){
    console.log(form.value.card);
    this.Card.emit(form.value.card)
    form.setValue({titular:this.dataUpdate.titular})
    
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="text-center mt-8 p-4 rounded-md shadow-sm shadow-gray-500">
    <h1 class="text-2xl text-gray-800 font-semibold my-4">Add Credit Card</h1>

    <form type="submit" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formCard)" #formCard="ngForm">
        <div class="flex items-center p-2 text-md">
            <i class="fas fa-user" [ngClass]="{
                'text-green-700':titular.valid,
                'text-red-600':!titular.valid && titular.touched     
            }"></i>
            <input type="text" name="titular" ngModel={{model.titular}}  #titular="ngModel" required minlength="5"
                class="outline-none w-full rounded-sm ml-4 p-1 text-black ring-2 border-l-8" placeholder="Nombre"
                [ngClass]="{
                    'border-green-700':titular.valid,
                    'border-red-600':!titular.valid && titular.touched
                        }">
        </div>
        <div class="flex p-2 items-center text-md">
            <i class="fas fa-credit-card" [ngClass]="{
                'text-green-700':numeroTarjeta.valid,
                'text-red-600':!numeroTarjeta.valid && numeroTarjeta.touched     
                    }"></i>
            <input type="text" ngModel={{model.numeroTarjeta}} name="numeroTarjeta" #numeroTarjeta="ngModel" required minlength="5" maxlength="5"
                class="outline-none w-full rounded-sm ml-4 p-1 text-black ring-2 border-l-8"
                placeholder="Numero Tarjeta" [ngClass]="{
                    'border-green-700':numeroTarjeta.valid,
                    'border-red-600':!numeroTarjeta.valid && numeroTarjeta.touched
                        }">
        </div>
        <div class="flex p-2 items-center text-md ">
            <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt" [ngClass]="{
                'text-green-700':fechaExpriracion.valid,
                'text-red-600':!fechaExpriracion.valid && fechaExpriracion.touched     
                    }"></i>
            <input type="text" ngModel={{model.fechaExpriracion}} name="fechaExpriracion" #fechaExpriracion="ngModel" required maxlength="10" minlength="10"
                class="outline-none w-full rounded-sm ml-4 p-1 text-black ring-2 border-l-8" 
                placeholder="Fecha Expedicion" [ngClass]="{
                    'border-green-700':fechaExpriracion.valid,
                    'border-red-600':!fechaExpriracion.valid && fechaExpriracion.touched
                        }">
        </div>
        <div class="flex p-2 items-center text-md ">
            <i class="fas fa-key" [ngClass]="{
                'text-green-700':cvvPassword.valid,
                'text-red-600':!cvvPassword.valid && cvvPassword.touched    
                    }"></i>
            <input type="password" ngModel={{model.cvvPassword}} name="cvvPassword" #cvvPassword="ngModel" required maxlength="3" minlength="3"
                class="outline-none w-full rounded-sm ml-4 p-1 text-black ring-2 border-l-8" placeholder="Numero Cvv"
                [ngClass]="{
                    'border-green-700':cvvPassword.valid,
                    'border-red-600':!cvvPassword.valid && cvvPassword.touched
                        }">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="!formCard.form.valid"
            class="btn-active"
            [ngClass]="{'btn-disable':!formCard.form.valid}"
            >Agregar</button>
    </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los datos de una variable de entrada la manera más sencillas es implementar `ngOnChanges` en el componente. A esta función le llegarán los nuevos datos cuando tus variables entrantes se hayan modificado.

En tu componente form debes añadir algo así:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.dataUpdate) this.dataUpdate = changes.dataUpdate.currentValue;
}
```

[En este artículo](https://www.acontracorrientech.com/uso-avanzado-de-los-componentes-en-angular-parte-3/) hablan sobre los ciclos de vida de un componente, entre los que está `ngOnChanges`.

Otra manera de obtener esos cambios es poniendo la variable de entrada con `get` y `set`. En ese caso sería:

```
_dataUpdate:Card;
@Input() 
set dataUpdate(value) {
    this._dataUpdate = value;
}

get dataUpdate() {
  return this.__dataUpdate; 
}
```

[En este artículo](https://ichi.pro/es/angular-tonto-input-setter-getter-vs-ngonchanges-267243092146470) hablan sobre este tema en mayor profundidad (por si te puede interesar )

De las 2 maneras, si los cambios se hacen sobre un objeto, y solo se modificara parcialmente, no se detectarían los cambios. [En este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34796901/angular2-change-detection-ngonchanges-not-firing-for-nested-object) (en inglés) hablan de posibles soluciones en estos casos (asignar nuevo objeto a variable de entrada o usar `ngDoCheck` para detectar esos cambios).

Espero te pueda servir.